# Ajax file upload is not working when used the second time

Tags: ajax, jquery, file-upload

I'm using this jquery plugin ajaxFileupload in our project. My design is I have a file upload control and set the opacity to 0.01 and then using an anchor link, I trigger the file upload control click event. This works fine until I try to click the anchor link the second time which it doesn't open the file dialog box.

Here is my code.

```
$(".btnUpload").live("click", function () {
    $(".lblUploadError").text("");
    $(".fleAttachment").trigger("click");
});
$(".fleAttachment").change(function () {
    var reg = /^.*\.(jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|jpeg|JPEG)$/;
    var vals = $(this).val(),
        val = vals.length ? vals.split("\\").pop() : "";
    if (reg.test(vals) == false) {
        $(".lblUploadError").text("Invalid Image Type. We only accept .GIF or .JPG");
    } else {
        ajaxFileUpload();
        eval($(".btnRefreshAttachmentList").attr("href"));
    }
});
```

I don't see any error in the console so it makes it difficult to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 $(".fleAttachment").change(function() {
```

to

```
 $(".fleAttachment").live('change', function() {
```

Comment: I know, but the code uses `.live()` so I reckon it must use an older version of jQuery. Nice point though.

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.7.1.min.js but when I try to use the on() it didn't work. Is .live() deprecated on new version?

Comment: According to [this](http://api.jquery.com/live/) the `.live` method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. Converting from `.live()` to `.on()` should be easy as they share the same syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".fleAttachment", function() {
//--> Logic Here // jQuery 1.7+
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.value="";
```

at the end should work